# Bootstrap nav bar not collapsing in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've been having trouble collapsing my navbar on my portfolio website when I'm using my mobile device or when the window is minimized. I modified this code from getbootstrap navbar section. Any help appreciated!

Here's my code:

```html
<!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="kulykarakoc.github.io">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#about">About Me</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Bootstrap so I'm going to assume you're using either Bootstrap v4 or Bootstrap v5.

If you're using Bootstrap v5, change the button attributes data-toggle and data-target to data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

The code you provided is working when using Bootstrap v4. If you're using Bootstrap v4 and you're still not able to toggle the navbar, make sure your project has the right setup.